# wamp server won't run error:(0xc000007b)

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp, msvcrt

I have installed wamp correctly from the website without any problem, I have launched it and it said:

```
msvcr110.dll missing.
```

I installed it and relaunched and I got

```
(0xc000007b)
```

error.

I looked for it, people said I would have to install vcredist_x64.exe.
I did install it and relaunched, it still didn't work.
I checked port 80 and it was available. Not skype nor firewall was blocking port 80.

Deleted it, the whole of it. Reinstalled everything, but it still doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Here you have pretty exhausting list of possible problems with solutions: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have found the solution to your problem by now but this is what happened to me while I was trying to install the 64bit version of wamp according to my pc:
Firstly I was having several dll errors, after looking for a solution I found a program that verifies if I have the required dll called check_vcredist, after installing them all, I was still facing this error.
I solved by uninstalling wamp and installing the 32bit version and now it works. I found this sugestion [here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,90472) .
If you found another solution to this problem, please share.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still struggling with this issue, just follow the installation guide and you should be able to install the latest (3.2.3) wamp server x64 version on windows 10 PCs.

1. On their [home page](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) at the bottom you can find download links for all the VS dependencies. Just download the `All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)` [zip](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/vcpackages/all_vc_redist_x86_x64.zip) and start installing all one by one.
2. Download `Checks VC++ packages installed` [tool](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe) from their website to validate if all the dependencies are installed properly.
3. Once above steps are completed and validated, you can start the wamp server installation again.

> Before start, make sure you don't have a partially installed wamp
> server. Remove and do it freshly if there is.
>
> Also install wamp on a root folder, not in to a sub folder. (Recommended to use the default path)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I had a few dll missing errors which i could solve by downloading them and installing in the system32 folder. Though i had 64bit version computer i downloaded the 32 bit as the 64 bit version dint work for me. I only thing we need to make sure is we have installed **C++ visual redistributable 2015** **version or higher**. Make sure u have the latest version of the C++ visual redistributable. Hope this works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read the instructions right when the installation opens - it has several links to required packages. Install them all one by one.

Then close the installation, and open it as administrator.

I followed this and managed to install it after looking everywhere for this problem.

Good luck!